# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).easyTicker is not a function

Tags: jquery

Earlier I was using the marquee tag but faced some issues when coming to cross browser compatibility.

So this is the reason I have shifted to Jquery Easy Ticker 
https://github.com/vaakash/jquery-easy-ticker

My requirement is, that I will be calling the backend from AJAX every 5 seconds to update the news feed.

This is my code:

```
function displaylivenews()
{
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < latestnewsresponse.length; i++)
    {
        s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + latestnewsresponse[i].link + '"  target="_">' + latestnewsresponse[i].title + "</a></div>";
        s += '<div class="itemDate">' + latestnewsresponse[i].pub_date + "</div>";
        mysource = latestnewsresponse[i].link.split("://")[1].split('/')[0].replace(/(www.)|(.com)/g, '');
        s += '<div class="Source">' + mysource + "</div>";
        s += '</li>'
    }
    //   jQuery("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>");
    $("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>").easyTicker(
    {
        direction: 'up'
    });
}
```

and this is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6n8ecLq6/10/

But when I am running this, I get folowing error in the browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).easyTicker is not a function

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you included all sources (no 404 for this plugin import) and is your function run after document has been loaded?

Comment: ya i included this plugin and loaded this in body section (fiddle) but still the same issue .

Comment: Using invalid resource path in fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with your fiddle is, you haven't included the required js for easyticker. The one which you added as the external resource is pointing to the git page. You need to download it in your local and refer that js after the jquery reference.

For the demo purpose, I've copied the entire js to the fiddle. Here is the demo.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to easyticker.js"></script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6n8ecLq6/11/)